# Change color of A element inside a div using inline css

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML like the following :

```
<p style="color:red">go <a href="SomeURLHere">here</a></p>
```

Where A element is produced by Server Side code I haven't access . 
In the browser *go* is red but *here* isn't due to some CSS code in the page's head element.
I'm wondering is there a way to make the link color inherit without adding style tags or JS codes in inappropriate place of HTML doc that would be stinky  . Note that I have no access to whole document but just this section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inherit` for color property, which means that color property value will be inherited from it's parent

In your case you can do:

```
<p style="color:inherit">go <a href="SomeURLHere" style="color: inherit;">here</a></p>
```

Comment: By default an anchor tag does not inherit attributes like color if an href attribute is present.

Comment: A element is produced by server side code , But as it seems you are the only here that knows what inline CSS means . Your answer is accepted

Answer (score 2):

You can put **style-tags** in your body.

```
<style>
  .red, .red a {
    color: red !important;
  }
<style>

<p class="red">go <a href="#">here</a></p>
```

Comment: This is correct! I don't know if @Vahid2015 needs red or inherit. But this solution will work for inherit as well!

Comment: Thank You . But I'm afraid that this is not an inline CSS

Comment: An anchor tag does not inherit attributes like color if an href attribute is present. So I don't see an inline solution.

Answer (score 1):

give a name to that div like this

`<style>`
`.vhd p, a{color:red}`
`</style>`
`<div class="vhd">`
`<p>go <a href="SomeURLHere">here</a></p>`
`</div>`

hope it will work for you

Comment: Thank you Harish but it's not inline . Is it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, What you are trying to do is not possible INLINE,

You can add style tags in your page if you are able to.

```html
<p class="red">go <a href="#">link</a></p>

<style>
.red a{
    color: red
}

.red{
    color: red;
}

</style>
```

Comment: The a element is produced server side he says.. So he can not change the a elements attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
      <style>
        red.a {
            backgrond-color: red;
        }

    </style>
    <div>
        <p class="red"><a href="#">here</a></p>
    </div>
   or u can use <p class="red"><a href="#" style="color:red;>"here</a></p>
```